# GLFW3 : accents in window title

Tags: c++, encoding, glfw

I am trying to get a window title with accents, calling glfwCreateWindow, but everytime i get stranges characters like "?" or "@". The only way i got the good result was with the following steps :

1- Set visual studio project to unicode instead of MBCS.

2- Encode the file in ANSI using a text editor.

What is the real way of doing that? I tried to set utf-8 as save encoding too, but it didn't worked.

Edit : My problem

Comment: Select a font which includes glyphs for the characters you are trying to display.

Comment: My problem is about the window title, not something Inside the window. I will edit my post.

Comment: This question has been answered in a never question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801165/cant-display-%c3%a4-in-glfw-window-title/73243415#73243415).