# Can't display 'ä' in GLFW window title

Tags: c++, glfw

```
glfwSetWindowTitle(win, "Nämen");
```

Becomes "N?men", where '?' is in a little black, twisted square, indicating that the character could not be displayed.

How do I display 'ä'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the GLFW implementation does not work according to the specification in this case. Probably the function still uses Latin-1 instead of UTF-8.

I had the same problem on GLFW 3.3 Windows 64 bit precompiled binaries and fixed it like this:

```
SetWindowTextA(glfwGetWin32Window(win),"Nämen")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use non-ASCII letters in the window title, then the string has to be utf-8 encoded.

[GLFW: Window title](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/window.html#window_title):

> The window title is a regular C string using the UTF-8 encoding. This means for example that, as long as your source file is encoded as UTF-8, you can use any Unicode characters.

If you see *a little black, twisted square* then this indicates that the `ä` is encoded with some iso encoding that is not UTF-8, maybe something like latin1. To fix this you need to open it in the editor in which you can change the encoding of the file, change it to uft-8 (without BOM) and fix the `ä` in the title.

Comment: Changing the encoding of `main.cpp` (in this case) to utf-8 (no bom) didn't work. Same question mark remains.

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not lie within GLFW but within the compiler. Encodings are handled by the major compilers as follows:

- Good guy *clang* assumes that every file is encoded in UTF-8
- Trusty *gcc* checks the system's settings<sup>1</sup> and falls back on UTF-8, when it fails to determine one.
- *MSVC* checks for BOM and uses the detected encoding; otherwise it assumes that file is encoded using the users current code page<sup>2</sup>.

You can determine your current code page by simply running `chcp` in your (Windows) console or PowerShell. For me, on a fresh install of Windows 11, it yields "850" (language: English; keyboard: German), which stands for [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

To fix this issue you have several solutions:

- Change your systems code page. Arguably the worst solution.
- Prefix your strings with `u8`, escape all unicode literals and convert the string to wide char before passing Win32 functions; e.g.:

```cpp
    const char* title = u8"\u0421\u043b\u0430\u0432\u0430\u0020\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0457\u043d\u0456\u0021";
    
    // This conversion is actually performed by GLFW; see footnote ^3
    const int l = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, title, -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = _malloca(l * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, title, -1, buf, l); 

    SetWindowTextW(hWnd, buf);
    _freea(buf);
```

- Save your source files with UTF-8 encoding **WITH BOM**. This allows you to write your strings without having to escape them. You'll still need to convert the string to a wide char string using the method seen above.
- Specify the `/utf-8` flag when compiling; this has the same effect as the previous solution, but you don't need the BOM anymore.

The solutions stated above still require you convert your good and nice string to a big chunky wide string.

Another option would be to provide a manifest<sup>4</sup> with the `activeCodePage` set to `UTF-8`. This way all Win32 functions with the `A`-suffix (e.g. `SetWindowTextA`) now accept and properly handle UTF-8 strings, if  the running system is at least or newer than Windows Version 1903.

---

## TL;DR

Compile your application with the `/utf-8` flag active.

**IMPORTANT**: This works for the Win32 APIs. This doesn't let you magically write Unicode emojis to the console like a hipster JS developer.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suppose it reads the LC_ALL setting on linux. In the last 6 years I have never seen a distribution, that does NOT specify UTF-8. However, take this information with a grain of salt; **I might be entirely wrong on how gcc handles this now**.

<sup>2</sup>  [If no byte-order mark is found, it assumes that the source file is encoded in the current user code page [...].](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170)

<sup>3</sup> GLFW performs the conversion as seen [here](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/0f9a9578f38518317d0b3305dd816ba7b400972d/src/win32_window.c#L1542).

<sup>4</sup> More about Win32 ANSI-APIs, Manifest and UTF-8 can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).